# Better solution to data storage and passing

Tags: c++, c++14

I'm trying to find a more elegant solution for some code I'm working on at the moment. I have data that needs to be stored then moved around, but I don't really want to take up any more space than I need to for the data that is stored.

I have 2 solutions, but neither seem very nice.

---

**Using inheritance and a tag**

```
enum class data_type{
    first, second, third
};

class data_base{
    public:
        virtual data_type type() const noexcept = 0;
};

using data_ptr = data_base*;

class first_data: public data_base{
    public:
        data_type type() const noexcept{return data_type::first;}

        // hold the first data type
};

// ...
```

Then you pass around a `data_ptr` and cast it to the appropriate type.

I really don't like this approach because it requires upwards casting and using bare pointers.

---

**Using a `union` and storing all data types**

```
enum class data_type{
    first, second, third
};

class data{
    public:
        data(data_type type_): type(type_){}
        data_type type;
        union{
            // first, second and third data types stored
        };
};
```

But I don't like this approach because then you start wasting a lot of memory when you have a large data type that may get passed around.

---

This data will then be passed onto a function that will parse it into a greater expression. Something like this:

```
class expression{/* ... */};
class expr_type0: public expression{/* ... */};
// every expression type

using expr_ptr = expression*;

// remember to 'delete'
expr_ptr get_expression(){
    data_ptr dat = get_data();        

    // interpret data
    // may call 'get_data()' many times
    expr_ptr expr = new /* expr_type[0-n] */

    delete dat;
    return expr;
}
```

and the problem arrises again, but it doesn't matter in this case because the `expr_ptr` doesn't need to be reinterpreted and will have a simple virtual function call.

---

What is a more elegant method of tagging and passing around the data to another function?

Comment: you could look at the likes of boost::variant and boost::any, but my question would be, "are you sure you want to apply polymorphism at the data item level, wouldn't it be better to make the data manipulators (record sets, table definitions) polymorphic instead?"

Comment: @RichardHodges Martin Fowler developed some nice patterns for this kind of stuff.

Comment: @RichardHodges I'm not using record sets *or* tables. This data is going to be interpreted into another type of data then never used again.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode I don't fully understand how the data class will be used. Are you saying that it's just for tranmission and reception of serialised data? Are you able to flesh out your example a little?

Comment: @RichardHodges The data is actually tokens that will be parsed into expressions, the question may get very long if I go too far into detail; but I'll add some more details.

Comment: A comment would be appreciated as to why the downvote.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ Do you have a reference to those patterns? It would be interesting to read.

Comment: @StianV.Svedenborg Here's an [overview of the patterns](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/), a full description is available in the accompanying book. Look into the Object-Relational- stuff in particular.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode I upvoted your comment about "A comment would be appreciated as to why the downvote", then noticed one of the downvotes was mine. Have no idea how this mistake happened. If you edit your question in any way, I'll gladly reverse it (it's currently locked in).

Comment: @CoffeeandCode I had a look at the link. It's essentially about creating an abstract database framework, right? In c++ i would suggest you prefer storing data by value. If the data is large it can privately marshalled to a shared_ptr impl to prevent copies. The abstraction of expressions is essentially already covered by c++ lambdas and function objects. Where you want to get polymorphic is on the data source/sink classes (data tables etc. in the link you posted).

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to envisage exactly what you're looking for without more information. But if I wanted some framework that allowed me to store and retrieve data in some structured way, in as-yet-unknown storage devices this is the kind of way I'd be thinking.

This may not be the answer you're looking for, but I think there'll be concepts here that will inspire you in the right direction.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <map>


// define some concepts

// bigfoo is a class that's expensive to copy - so lets give it a shared-handle idiom
struct bigfoo {

    struct impl {
        impl(std::string data) : _data(std::move(data)) {}
        void write(std::ostream& os) const {
            os << "I am a big object. Don't copy me: " << _data;
        }
    private:
        std::string _data;
    };

    bigfoo(std::string data) : _impl { std::make_shared<impl>(std::move(data)) } {};

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&os, const bigfoo& bf) {
        bf._impl->write(os);
        return os;
    }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<impl> _impl;
};

// all the data types our framework handles
using abstract_data_type = boost::variant<int, std::string, double, bigfoo>;

// defines the general properties of a data table store concept
template<class...Columns>
struct table_definition
{
    using row_type = std::tuple<Columns...>;
};

// the concept of being able to store some type of table data on some kind of storage medium
template<class IoDevice, class TableDefinition>
struct table_implementation
{
    using io_device_type = IoDevice;
    using row_writer_type = typename io_device_type::row_writer_type;

    template<class...Args> table_implementation(Args&...args)
    : _io_device(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
    {}

    template<class...Args>
    void add_row(Args&&...args) {
        auto row_instance = _io_device.open_row();
        set_row_args(row_instance,
                     std::make_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...),
                     std::index_sequence_for<Args...>());
        row_instance.commit();
    }

private:
    template<class Tuple, size_t...Is>
    void set_row_args(row_writer_type& row_writer, const Tuple& args, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
    {
        using expand = int[];
        expand x { 0, (row_writer.set_value(Is, std::get<Is>(args)), 0)... };
        (void)x; // mark expand as unused;
    }

private:
    io_device_type _io_device;
};

// model the concepts into a concrete specialisation

// this is a 'data store' implementation which simply stores data to stdout in a structured way
struct std_out_io
{
    struct row_writer_type
    {
        void set_value(size_t column, abstract_data_type value) {
            // roll on c++17 with it's much-anticipated try_emplace...
            auto ifind = _values.find(column);
            if (ifind == end(_values)) {
                ifind = _values.emplace(column, std::move(value)).first;
            }
            else {
                ifind->second = std::move(value);
            }
        }

        void commit()
        {
            std::cout << "{" << std::endl;
            auto sep = "\t";
            for (auto& item : _values) {
                std::cout << sep << item.first << "=" << item.second;
                sep = ",\n\t";
            }
            std::cout << "\n}";
        }

    private:
        std::map<size_t, abstract_data_type> _values;  // some value mapped by ascending column number
    };

    row_writer_type open_row() {
        return row_writer_type();
    }
};

// this is a model of a 'data table' concept
using my_table = table_definition<int, std::string, double, bigfoo>;


// here is a test
auto main() -> int
{
    auto data_store = table_implementation<std_out_io, my_table>( /* std_out_io has default constructor */);
    data_store.add_row(1, "hello", 6.6, bigfoo("lots and lots of data"));

    return 0;
}
```

expected output:

```
{
        0=1,
        1=hello,
        2=6.6,
        3=I am a big object. Don't copy me: lots and lots of data
}
```